# When do I need `--exclude=*` in an `rsync` call?

Tags: rsync

I sometimes read `--exclude=*` in `rsync` calls. But I don't really understand why I need them there.

- What is the effect of it?
- In wich use-cases should it be used?

The question is not about `--exclude` option in general. It is about using it with the wildcard `*`.

Comment: Have you performed a Google search for rsync flags, specifically the exclude flag?

Comment: @spikey_richie I never use Google directly.I would recommend DuckDuckGo.com - maybe with the `!g' bang. ;) To your question: Maybe it depends on my none-native english that I am not able to fully describe what my question is about. It is about a deeper understanding. The manpage explanations doesn't help me here. That is why I am asking. I didn't ask how it works. I asked about use-cases ("When") for this feature.

Comment: --exclude is used to exclude from rsync specific file names, specific file types, or specific sub-directories. Have a look here for some use cases http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks for the URL which show interesting use cases. But none of them fit to my question.

Comment: Can you add a real life example? And does that then also specify some `--include` flags?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/803212/understanding-rsyncs-include-exclude-patterns